# Iterating regex submatches represented as std::basic_string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, tokenize

Is there a direct efficient way to convert [`std::sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) to [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (without constructing an intermediate `std::basic_string` and without intermediate heap allocation)? Or one abstraction level further, is there an alternative to [`std::regex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) for iterating regex submatches represented as [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of [`std::sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) using the `std` (C++17)?

The reasons why I rather like to use [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) over [`std::sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) are:

- [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) refers to a constant contiguous sequence of char-like objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero. This enables the usage of [`charconv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/charconv)'s [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) (which surprisingly is not implemented using `ForwardIterator`s). This does not seem to be the case for [`std::sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match), since it is represented as a pair of `BidirectionalIterator`s.
- [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) has a much richer string-like interface facilitating additional context-sensitive tokenization in some exceptional cases for some file formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no general way to detect whether an iterator is contiguous. We can still handle known contiguous iterators - such as those of `std::string`:

```
std::string_view as_sv(std::ssub_match m) {
    if(!m.matched) return {};
    return { &*m.first, m.second - m.first };
}
```

Handling the remaining named specializations of `sub_match` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Is the matched check required? Alternatively: `return { &*m.first, m.length() }` (length will return zero in case of no match)

Comment: Yes. Otherwise `&*m.first` may not be valid.