# function which takes a string as input and splits it into words. Punctuation characters should be ignored

Tags: c++

I wrote a feature but an error popped up. and I don't know how to solve it.
And in general, am I properly moving in the implementation of the wind-up?

```
void Split(char* str) 
{
    const char* punctuation = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=,./?;:'";
    char* ch = strtok(str, punctuation);

    while (ch) 
    {              
        std::cout << ch << '\n';
        ch = strtok(0, punctuation);
    }
}
```

Error - Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: You should be using the `ispunct` function instead of creating your own string.  Then when you have that, you use search / replace functions, using the `ispunct` as an indicator as to whether the current character is a punctuation or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the top of your file as follows.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Or instead of `strtok`, try to use `strtok_s` and take a look at [this cppreference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: Did not help((  I added - #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__1

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer regex-based tokenizing from C++11 over C functions `strtok` or `strtok_s`:

```
void split(const std::string& s)
{
   std::regex rgx("[~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=,./?;:']+");
   std::sregex_token_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), rgx, -1);
   std::sregex_token_iterator end;
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
      std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

IMO, it's much better since it works with `std::string` insted of char arrays (C strings).

A simple use case:

```
std::string s("some`string?to+-be;:'tokenized");
split(s);
```

[Live demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Cw7qRd3rBldShLsh).

---

Note that this will create `std::string` objects for sub-matches, which may represent some overhead (though possibly reduced by short string optimization). This question discusses how to turn sub-matches into `std::string_view` objects: [Iterating regex submatches represented as std::basic_string_view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50676058/580083)
.

A solution might in the form of rewriting the loop might look like:

```
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
{
   std::string_view sv(&*iter->first, iter->length());
   std::cout << sv << std::endl;
}
```